# Regex to strip replace string inside last square brackets

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is an example of the string:

```
section[12256][1008][2]
```

I want to replace the string inside the last [] brackets i.e. [2]

Can someone please provide a regex that I can use inside the replace method?i.e. `name.replace(/\[.*?\]/g, "[" + index + "]");`
Problem with this is, it replaces the content in every square bracket.

Also, what if there is some string after the last [] i.e. section[12256][1008][1].MaxNumberOfColumns. 
What does the regex expression become?

Comment: Try this `"section[12256][1008][2]".replace(/\[\d+\]$/g, '[100]')`

Answer (score 1):

```js
var str = 'section[12256][1008][2].MaxNumberOfColumns';
var index = 45;
var val = str.replace( /(.*\])(\[[0-9]*\])(?:.*)$/g , '$1[' +index+ ']' );
  document.write(val);

document.write('<hr>');

str = 'section[12256][1008][457683]';
index = 12;
val = str.replace( /(.*\])(\[[0-9]*\])(?:.*)$/g , '$1[' +index+ ']' );
  document.write(val);
```

Comment: If the string has anything after the last bracket the above doesn't work. i.e. section[12256][1008][1].MaxNumberOfColumns What does the regex become?

Comment: this is not the same question as initial ! but i updated my answer to reflect your needs.